# Блокировки транзакций entity postgres

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework, wcf

Для хранения данных мы используем posgrtes 9.6.3
Обработка данных выполняется с помощью Entity Framefork в wcf службе. Используется принцип DataBase First.
Нам потребовалась реализация долго живущих транзакций. Для добавления сложных объектов на длительном промежутки времени. Список созданных констекстов хранится в статическом списке. Транзакции фиксируются и уничтожаются в нужный момент.

Пример открытия транзакции

```
        this.Db = new context();
        this.Db.Database.Connection.Open();
        this._Transaction = this.Db.Database.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted);
```

Далее полученный объект добавляется в общий список транзакций

Проблема заключается в том, что при выполнении нескольких одинаковых транзакций первая транзакция блокирует последующие. Блокировка возникает, когда в транзакция А (первая созданная транзакция) вставляется запись в таблицу, добавлении происходит успешно. Когда транзакция Б (позже созданная транзакция) выдается вставить запись в эту же таблицу генерируется исключение. В базе видно, что транзакция Б блокируется транзакцией А. Когда эти же запросы, сгенерированные Entity, выполняются из клиента или с помощью Npgsql провайдера (wcf) все транзакции успешно выполняются.
В чем причина такого поведения?

Answer (score 2):

> долго живущих транзакций

Не надо так делать. Вообще не надо так делать с PostgreSQL. Любая длительная транзакция мешает работе `autovacuum`. Если плохо работает `autovacuum` - то будет плохо всем выполняющимся запросам. Потому что они вынуждены будут перебирать больший объём старых версий строк для проверки видимости в своей транзакции. Несколько секунд поиск по уникальному ключу и CPU в потолок - это из реального опыта у часто обновляемой таблицы.

> IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted

[Не реализован в PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/transaction-iso.html). Я серьёзно. Вы можете запросить `Read Uncommitted` потому что SQL-стандарт требует воспринимать эту синтаксическую конструкцию и реализовать требования к этому уровню изоляции. Но в PostgreSQL при этом будет использоваться всё равно `Read Committed`. Это допустимое стандартом поведение, грязные чтения на этом уровне изоляции допускаются, но реализация грязных чтений не требуется.

> при выполнении нескольких одинаковых транзакций первая транзакция блокирует последующие

Следовательно, последующие транзакции хотят получить блокировки, конфликтующие с блокировками, взятыми в первой транзакции. Большинство взятых блокировок удерживается до окончания транзакции.

Поскольку вы наблюдаете иное поведение при смене клиента - значит вина на клиенте, он что-то делает не так либо делает дополнительно. Включите на тестовой машине логирование всех запросов к базе и посмотрите, чем различается поведение клиентов и какие дополнительные блокировки те желают получить в транзакции. Скорей всего выполняется что-то неявно.

Логировать выполняемые запросы можно указанием параметра `log_min_duration_statement = 0;` глобально по всех базе в `postgresql.conf` или для отдельного пользователя:

```
alter user melkij set log_min_duration_statement = 0;
-- для выключения после reset
alter user melkij reset log_min_duration_statement;
```

Comment: Благодарю за ответ. Запросы брались именно из логов, ни каких других  запросов entity не генерирует, но блокировки почему-то появляются. Придется отказать от идеи с транзакциями.